# How to force xelatex to convert eps into pdf? speed issue with slow compilation of xelatex

Tags: xetex

I run a few simple tests to compare the compilation speed of pdflatex and xelatex. As most people said, I also found that xelatex is always much slower than pdflatex.

**The reason for the slowness of xelatex I figured out is eps conversion process in xelatex.**

I use eps image files created by Adobe Illustrator, and the average size of the eps file is 1MB. It seems that very time I compiled using xelatex, it will spend considerable time to convert the eps file. But pdflatex convert eps to pdf using "epstopdf" package only once in the first compilation. After the first compilation, pdflatex just use the converted pdf image file. The good thing is those converted pdf image file is significantly smaller than the original eps file, just around 20K.

I tried to use the pdf image file that generated by pdflatex in xelatex, it does speed up the compilation process significantly, though still not as fast as pdflatex, but made a big progress.

But "epstopdf" is not working in xelatex. **Is there any other method to force xelatex to convert eps image into pdf file on the fly, so it can use pdf image file ever since the first compilation just as "epstopdf" does in pdflatex?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out a way myself, and found it working pretty good. So I answer my own question here. It is a method of using external .bat in Three steps.

**First**, create a bat file named `conversion.bat` in the latex directory with the contents as below

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%G in (*.eps) do @if not exist "%%~nG.pdf" (epstopdf "%%G") else (
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B /O:D "%%G" "%%~nG.pdf"') do set newest=%%~xi) & (
if !newest!==.eps echo "%%G" modification time is newer & (epstopdf "%%G") else (
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B /T:C /O:D "%%G" "%%~nG.pdf"') do set newest=%%~xi) & (
if !newest!==.eps echo "%%G" creation time is newer & (epstopdf "%%G")))))
```

Explanation: The above cmd batch code will first compare the modification time of .eps and .pdf, if there are .eps files which modification time is newer then run `epstopdf` to convert them. Then compare the creation time of .eps and .pdf, also convert the newer .eps file.

**Second**, in your latex document, add

```
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{conversion.bat}

text here

\end{document}
```

**Third**, if you are using `winedt` set `option-->excution modes-->console application-->xelatex-->switches` as `--shell-escape`.

Now compile your document. The external `conversion.bat` will automatically handle .eps conversion to .pdf

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply call once `epstopdf file.eps` to convert your eps before running xelatex?

Beside this: Converting the file on the fly when it doesn't exist is not so difficult. E.g. compile this with `xelatex --shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{testeps1.pdf}{}{\immediate\write18{epstopdf testeps1.eps}}
\includegraphics{testeps1}
\end{document}
```

But epstopdf doesn't convert only when the file doesn't exist but also compares file dates and updates the file if the eps has been changed and this is more difficult to implement in xelatex as some of the primitives used seem not to exist. So when you change the eps you must ensure that you trigger the conversion again.

Comment: Thank you. So is it impossible to write latex code to compare file dates? I just feel that there should be a way to do this, because the package "epstopdf" can do this.

Comment: By the way, how to convert all eps files in the same directory in a single command line using "epstopdf"?

Comment: Depending on your shell `for i in *.eps; do epstopdf $i; done` would work.

Comment: No it is not impossible. In the same way as xelatex can call epstopdf it could also call some script which first which compares the dates and then calls epstopdf if needed.

Comment: If you have several file dependencies and multiple working steps that should be date aware there is a simple solution,  use make

Comment: @MaxNoe But how to do this, I have no experience in calling script in latex. Could you please give a demonstration?

Comment: @DG' Maybe naive question. I use windows cmd. I typed `for %i in (*.eps) do epstopdf %i`. It shows errors says`Error: Unknown option or too many input files (try --help for more information)
D:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:652: command failed with exit code 255:perl.exe d:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/scripts/epstopdf/epstopdf.pl d:/w/physics teaching material/general physics/homework/assignment/hw8-assignment/general frict
ionless slop.eps`. What is wrong?

Comment: @DG' I know cmd is different from other shell, so I google for cmd tutorials. This command should be right, because `for %i in (*.eps) do echo %i` works! And a single line `epstopdf name.eps` works in my cmd. I just can't figure out why `for %i in (*.eps) do epstopdf %i` didn't work.

Comment: @user15964 You have spaces in your file name (bad idea), so you must use quotes: `for %i in (*.eps) do epstopdf  "%i"`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works! Thank you so much! Could you please show me how to call a external .bat file in latex? What I think is to write the file date comparison and eps conversion code into the external .bat file, then call it in latex at the very beginning.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Or maybe just embedded the .bat code into latex document, but let latex know to run this part of the code in windows cmd shell. Is it possible in latex?

Comment: `\immediate\write18{myscript.bat}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hi, UlrikeFischer! Thank you for your answer, I figure out a way myself  by using external .bat file. I posted an answer. But I still want to embed the .bat code into latex, so I won't have to copy the bat file everytime. Do you know how to embed my bat into latex?

Comment: Why do want to have the .bat in every document folder?  Put the .bat somewhere in your PATH (or add the path to the bat to your PATH environment variable).

Comment: You might need to add - - shell-escape to your LaTeX call

Answer (score 0):

If your document becomes more and more complex, you should think about automating things.

A great tool for this is Make: 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

You have to write a `Makefile`, which is a simple text file (but without ending).
A Makefile is a set of rules which describe how a `target` is made and which dependencies it has.

All rules look similiar to this:

```
target: dependecy1 dependency2 ... 
       command1
       command2
```

When you call a simple `make` in a directory with a Makefile in it, make runs the first rule it encounters. It builds a tree of the dependencys and processes them from top to bottom. It ckecks which files are dependencies are newer than the last target version und just runs the commands if it is necessary.

By convention the first rule should be `all`, which should build your final targets.

So for a LaTeX case with bibliography with biblatex/biber this would maybe look like this:

```
all: mydocument.pdf

mydocument.pdf: mydocument.tex myreferences.tex
    xelatex mydocument.tex
    biber mydocument.bcf
    xelatex mydocument.tex
    xelatex mydocument.tex
```

If you need to convert figures from eps to pdf it would make sense to put them into their own folders and define a rule that converts them to pdf.

This would look like this:

```
all: mydocument.pdf

mydocument.pdf: mydocument.tex converted/fig1.pdf converted/fig2.pdf
    xelatex mydocument.tex

converted/%.pdf: epsfigures/%.pdf
     epstopdf $< --outfile=$@
```

`$@` is the name of the target file and `$<` is the first dependency, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html.
The `%` matches all files with the patterns around it.

However, this requires the `converted` directory to exist. Sou one should add a rule that creates the directory and add it as a static dependency (static dependencys are not checked for a date, they just have to exist.). These dependencies come after the regular ones, separated by a pipe `|`:

```
all: mydocument.pdf

mydocument.pdf: mydocument.tex converted/fig1.pdf converted/fig2.pdf
    xelatex mydocument.tex

converted/%.pdf: epsfigures/%.pdf | converted
     epstopdf $< --outfile=$@

converted:
    mkdir -p converted
```

Another handy convention is, that there should be a rule named `clean` which deletes all output that the Makefile created. Here the tex option `--output-directory=<dir>` comes in handy. If we use a directory build for the LaTeX output, the clean method just has to delete `build` and `converted`.
Also TeX usually should not stop if an error occured if you use automatic build system like make.

To show you how a Makefile handles variables, i put the texoption in a variable:

```
texoptions = --interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=build
all: build/mydocument.pdf

build/mydocument.pdf: mydocument.tex converted/fig1.pdf converted/fig2.pdf | build
    xelatex $(texoptions) mydocument.tex

converted/%.pdf: epsfigures/%.pdf | converted
     epstopdf $< --outfile=$@

converted:
    mkdir -p converted

build:
    mkdir -p build


clean:
    rm -rf build
    rm -rf converted
```

You can call a single rule by `make <rule>`. So `make clean` would delete all your created files for a clean start, e.g. after an error occured.

Comment: Hi, MaxNoe! I figure out a way using pure cmd batch and posted it as an answer. Any suggestions is welcome. Especially, I want to know if there is a way to embed the bat code into latex, so I won't need external bat files.

Comment: you could do it with a filecontents environment

Comment: But there are many "%" symbol

Comment: and what is more, `filecontents` can't write .bat file directly.

Comment: why not? And a filecontents environment is put out verbatim no need to escape LaTeX symbols.

Comment: If you use the starred version even the comment line is not written. So why does `\begin{filecontents*}{myscript.bat} your batch code here \end{filecontents*}` not work for you?

Comment: Because due to security issue, latex didn't allow to write .bat file. I was thinking to embed code into `\write18{}`. But I failed to do it.